# Simulating factory manufacture with simpy by requesting multiple resources at the same time, but running for different time

Tags: python, simulation, simpy, event-simulation

I was trying to simulate a factory manufacturing different products with different machines with `simpy`. For each product, we will need to allocate different machines for production. For example, the first product will ask for machines 1, 2, 5 sequentially and the second product requires machines 2, 3, and 5. For my case, I will be given a list of products we are going to manufacture and the corresponding information to make the products. One example is shown below.

[image: Given workflow for product manufacturation]

My situation was unlike most `simpy` simulations. I want to simulate the process of the given list of processes (with information on the machine and running time). Please note that the given list of processes comes with unfixed length, which is saying the program does not know how many events and which resources to allocate beforehand.

My problem is how to deal with the event dependencies and how to deal with requesting resources for the cases shown in the figure. A simplified example is to use `ExitStack` as a generalized way of context manager to request resources to run for the same duration, e.g. [Requesting multiple resources simultaneously](https://groups.google.com/g/python-simpy/c/MO-U4ub_o64). But for my case, the dependent events (e.g. A2 and A3 in the first workflow) may run for a different duration. One may think that I can request the maximum running time out of A2 and A3. But this leads to undesired resource waste.

Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

I have tried to Google everything online and learned the most related case is [Requesting multiple resources simultaneously](https://groups.google.com/g/python-simpy/c/MO-U4ub_o64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: it seems like each job could be split into parts which can be run independently, and which a later part depends on ?
e.g. for the first one (colored in green):

- product_1_1 (processed on `A1` and `A2`)
- product_1_2 (processed on `A3`)
- product_1 (processed on `A4` and `A5`, depending on `product_1_1` and `product_1_2`, so that it can only be started after both predecessors are completed)

This way, the problem could be described as a job shop with additional precedence constraints (between last/first tasks of different jobs belonging to the same product).

This could also make it simpler to create a simulation model, since each job (no matter whether its preceding another job or not) can just request the resource it needs for every step (and for the exact duration this step takes).
To notify a dependent job of the completion of the jobs it depends on, a simpy [`AllOf`](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.events.html#simpy.events.AllOf) event could be used:

```
all_preceding_jobs_completed = AllOf(env, preceding_jobs_completion_events)
all_preceding_jobs_completed.callbacks.append(job.mark_ready)
```

---

just for illustration, a simpy/casymda-model for the described problem could look like this:
(for the sake of a simple animation just 6 machines are modeled, instead of a flexible number)
[image: casymda-animation]

Each machine may just process one job at a time, and jobs cycle through the process until completed, waiting for machines as needed. The two depending jobs `product_1` and `product_2` are released when all predecessors were completed. [sample code on github](https://github.com/fladdimir/casymda-job-shop-with-precedence)

In the animated example model, each job is naively released from the buffer as soon as it becomes ready (all predecessor jobs completed, or immediately in case there are no predecessors), resulting in a makespan of 87.
(To find better schedules (for more complex cases) it might also be interesting to look for an analytical solution e.g. as described here https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop)

Comment: This is very close to the way I figured it out. The detailed implementation is not the same but shares the same idea. I love the illustration! Thank you very much! I may ask following up questions if I have any.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to implement what fladdimir suggested.

I start with data tables, use dicts to build a dependency tree, and recursion to convert everything into a simpy model.

The main feature is how the tasks are dynamically put together.  Changing the data changes the structure of the nodes in the model.  There is no product prototypes.

```
"""
Simpy demo showing how to dynamicaly chain
together tasks to make a process.

a task can have more then one pressedent
and the task will wait for all pressedents to
finish before starting

programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy

# each machine type has it own resource pool
# This allows testing the addition of 
# machines to relieve a bottle necks
machine_pools_data = [
    # machine name, qty
    ['a1', 1],
    ['a2', 1],
    ['a3', 1],
    ['a4', 1],
    ['a5', 1],
    ['a6', 1],    
]

# defines a job made up of tasks
# each task uses a machine for x amount of time
# and it output goes to a next task.
jobs_data = [
    # job id, task id, machine, time, next task
    ['p1', 1, 'a1', 17, 2],
    ['p1', 2, 'a2', 30, 4],
    ['p1', 3, 'a3', 14, 4],
    ['p1', 4, 'a4', 15, 5],
    ['p1', 5, 'a5', 25, -1],

    ['p2', 1, 'a1', 13, 3],
    ['p2', 2, 'a3', 15, 3],
    ['p2', 3, 'a2', 10, 4],
    ['p2', 4, 'a6', 20, -1],
]


def task(env, job_id, task_id, machine_pool, time, precedent_tasks):
    """
    hart of the processing

    waits for the completions of pressidenct tasks (list can be empty)
    grabs a resouce
    spend some time doing the task
    """
        
    print(f'{env.now}, job: {job_id}, task_id: {task_id}, waitting for pressedents')
    
    yield env.all_of(precedent_tasks)

    print(f'{env.now}, job: {job_id}, task_id: {task_id}, getting resource')
    with machine_pool.request() as req:
        
        yield req

        print(f'{env.now}, job: {job_id}, task_id: {task_id}, starting task')

        yield env.timeout(time)

    print(f'{env.now}, job: {job_id}, task_id: {task_id}, finished task')


def build_pools(env, pool_data):
    """
    builds a dict of resouces pools from data

    index 0: name of machine type
    index 1: number of machines in the pool
    """

    pools = {}

    for pool in pool_data:
            pools[pool[0]] = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=pool[1])

    return pools

def build_jobs(env, pools, job_data):
    """
    builds a tree of tasks where the root node
    is the exit of the job, and leaf nodes
    start the job.  leaf nodes have no pressidents
    there can be more then one leaf node.
    there can only be one root node
    """
      
    jobs = {}


    # prime the node tree with default empty nodes
    for job in job_data:
        tasks = jobs.setdefault(job[0],{})
        tasks[job[1]] = []

        if job[4] < 0:
             # add exit node
             tasks[-1] = []

    # fill in pressedents for each node
    # leaf nodes end with empty pressident lists
    for job in job_data:
         
        tasks = jobs[job[0]] # tasks for job
        press = tasks[job[4]] # get pressident list for task
        press.append(job) # add pressedent node data

    # start a recursive process that
    # walks the node tree, creating the tasks
    for job in jobs.keys():
         tasks = jobs[job]

         exit_node = tasks[-1][0]

         build_tasks(env, tasks, exit_node, pools)

def build_tasks(env, tasks, node, pools):
    """
    recurse down the pressidents and work from the
    leafs back creating tasks, which are used as
    pressident events for the parent node.
    """

    press_tasks = []

    press_nodes = tasks[node[1]] # get list of pressident nodes

    # recurse the pressidents to get task processes that
    # this node can use to wait on.
    for press_node in press_nodes:
        press_tasks.append(build_tasks(env, tasks, press_node, pools))

    # create the task process
    t = task(env, node[0], node[1], pools[node[2]], node[3], press_tasks)

    # retrun the process to the parent, which the parent
    # will wait on as a pressident
    t = env.process(t)

    return t


# boot up
env = simpy.Environment()

pools = build_pools(env, machine_pools_data)

build_jobs(env, pools, jobs_data)

env.run(100)

print('done')
```